# Creating a query based on creation date

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, date

I am trying to figure out how to create a query based on creation date. I tried the following:

```
select
s.emailaddress
, s.subscriberkey
, s.status
, s.datejoined
from _subscribers s
where s.dateJoined >= dateadd(d,-1, cast(getDate() as date))
```

But I receive the following error:

> Error saving the Query field.Field 'Contact ID' is a required for the
>   Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query
>   text.

Comment: what date are you trying to query? Yesterday and today?

Comment: I'm trying to query any new user that comes into the system from June until the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Error saving the Query field.Field 'Contact ID' is a required for the
>   Target Data Extension. Ensure this field is specified in your query
>   text.

This means that ContactID is set to a required / non-nullable in the target data extension. To overcome this, you either have to include it in your query, delete it from the target data extension or make it nullable (not required)

Comment: Thank you! I'm super super new to queries here so if I were to add the 'contact id' to my existing query what would that look like?

Comment: Problem is that "ContactID" is not in the _Subscribers Data view (not even sure if it is in any data view).  I would suggest either deleting this field from the target DE or investigation to see whether it is a system value or not.

Comment: You are welcome @Nicole . If this answer helped then you should accept it :)